# Reading multiple lines from a List with one iteration

Tags: java, csv, iteration, row, across

When reading a CSV file, I want to remember/store data across multiple rows of that particular file, e.g. to make an object based on columns from line 1+2, line 3+4, etc.

While I've found a solution, I do believe there should a 'cleaner' solution for this. This is what I came up with:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (var reader = new FileReader("src/main/java/com/kdh/snippets/loops/dummy.csv")) {
        List<String[]> rows = CsvReader.read(reader);

        var index1 = 0;
        var index2 = 1;

        // 50 lines in file = 25 iterations
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.size() / 2; i++) {
            String[] consumption = rows.get(index1);
            String[] injection = rows.get(index2);
            System.out.println("Consumption: " + consumption[8] + ", Injection: " + injection[8]);
            index1 += 2;
            index2 += 2;
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: tbh: This looks totally fine. There may be a performance problem when you get a `List` that has no `O(1)` access time on its `get()` method (i.e. when using a `LinkedList`). An alternative would be to use an `iterator()` on which you just call `next()` twice per iteration

Answer (score 0):

> I do believe there should a 'cleaner' solution for this.

It's not clear what you have in mind when you say "cleaner", but here are some suggestions that I think would improve your code:

1. Consider reading CSV lines as you need them, instead of slurping them all into memory first, then going back and iterating over them.  If you were using [the `CsvReader` of OpenCSV](https://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVReader.html), then that would imply using the `readNext()` method instead of the `readAll()` method.  It's unclear if or how the same could be done with the unspecified `CsvReader` you're actually using.
2. Use an object that represents the current state of the iteration instead of iterating by index.  If you persist in collecting all the lines into a `List`, then that would mean using the list's `Iterator` to obtain individual lines.  If you implement the above suggestion (1), then the `CsvReader` itself would be the wanted object.
3. With (2) in place, simply loop until the source of lines has no more (pairs of) lines to provide.

For example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (var reader = new CsvReader(
            new FileReader("src/main/java/com/kdh/snippets/loops/dummy.csv"))) {
        for (String[] line = reader.nextLine(); line != null; line = reader.nextLine()) {
            String consumption = line[8];

            line = reader.nextLine();
            if (line == null) {
                // warn about an odd number of lines?
                break;
            }
            String injection = line[8];

            System.out.println("Consumption: " + consumption + ", Injection: " + injection);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: `String production` -> `String injection`.